# I don't remember "I have a girlfriend" / "having a girlfriend" - are there differences?

Tags: meaning

**Example 1**

> I don't remember **I have a girlfriend**.

**Example 2**

> I don't remember **having a girlfriend**.

I wonder if the two clauses in bold can be interpreted differently.

Example 1: It sounds like I have a girlfriend, but I deny this fact.

Example 2: It sounds like the thing of me having a girlfriend is not in my head.

Or they mean the same, both saying that me having a girlfriend is not in my head, whether it is a reality or not.

Comment: #1 is wrong, because we "remember" a noun phrase, and "have a girlfriend" isn't a noun phrase.  You could say "**that** I have a girlfriend", though.

Comment: https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/2b43034a-be04-4466-a233-51debee32966

Comment: What are you trying to say? You don't know if you have a girlfriend right now? You don't know if you have ever had a girlfriend in your life? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

'I don't remember that I have a girlfriend.' refers to the present.

'(don't) remember having' refers to the past. We remember doing something after we have done it.

'I don't remember having a girlfriend.' means that I don't remember that I **had** a girlfriend.

[ I remember locking the door.(= I locked the door and now I remember this) ]

Answer (score 0):

> I don't remember I have a girlfriend.

should be

> I don't remember that I have a girlfriend.

The girlfriend you don't remember is  your girlfriend right now, in the present.  You could say this when reporting in the present tense how you flirted with someone else at a party just last night.

You might say

> I don't remember having a girlfriend.

when describing your life some years ago.

Comment: I think "I don't remember having a girlfriend" could refer to any time in the past, though, even the very recent past.  For example, if I come home with groceries and put them away, but then a minute later I see the milk on the dinner table, I might say, "Funny, I don't remember leaving the milk on the dinner table."  It's a little harder to imagine an example for "having a girlfriend", but it sounds like something somebody might say after getting hit on the head and having amnesia!

Comment: @stangdon I agree, The correct construction for the situation in the question really depends on context information the OP has not provided.